# Run Multiple Projects (csproj) in Single Solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor

I am building a Blazor web assembly project along with a server-side API for it to hit. I can compile and run the debug of the Blazor web assembly project. Now that i have added the server-side API, I would like to be able to have it run in debug mode for dev purposes also. Ideally, I would like to be able to start a debug session and have it fire up the web assembly and API project concurrently. That way, I can test my code on both sides (client/server) for my ajax calls. The structure is multiple projects in a single solution. Can I fire both at the same time from within a single VS instance (Mac btw)?

Comment: This is possible in Visual Studio for Windows. Not sure about the Mac version which has a totally different code base derived from MonoDevelop.

Comment: How would you set it up in Windows? Configure something in the .sln file? Perhaps going through that might help.

Comment: In VS for Windows you right click on the Solution Item (not a Project Item) in the Solution Explorer and select `Set Startup Projects. ...` (note the plural) from the context menu.

Comment: How does that change the .sln file?

Comment: It doesn't.  This information is stored in user specific files. Maybe *.suo.

Comment: [Here is the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/set-startup-projects?view=vsmac-2022) on setting multiple startup projects for VS on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks, Lex. I am new to the Mac version of VS and things are in different locales. ;)

Comment: @ClayHess, not sure if you already use it, but [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) makes testing and debugging your APIs a lot easier. They have a Mac version of that tool as well.